# Time difference calculation issues

Tags: java

I have a table called by name **Symbols** in my Application which will be updated continously for every **8** minutes

Each record inside the Symbol table  has got a attribute by name **updated-at** and whose value is in timestamp as shown

```
 "updated_at" : NumberLong("1375715967249")
```

I have a task to show the updated data to the users from the symbols table

In case the symbol is not updated for 9  minutes , i need to executed a particular task and if updated a different task

I was following this logic , please let me know if this has got any loop holes ?? ( I mean like day like settings --- or any such )

```
package com;

public class UnixTimeConversion {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long timeStamp = 1375715967249l;
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        long currtime = date.getTime();
        if ((currtime - timeStamp) > 600000) {
            System.out.println("Greater than 10 minutes since executed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Lesser than 10 minutes since executed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 minute !=  600000 ms...

Comment: No but ten minutes is

Comment: I would use System.currentTimeMillis() instead of wrapping it with a Date and then unwrapping it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks but is using System.currentTimeMillis() in a high multitheread application is safe or not ??

Comment: The code as you show it wouldn't have a problem, but if the clock is changed, the difference (currtime - timestamp) could be a negative number.  Just something to keep in mind if you use the difference for making any calculations later.

Comment: @sbaker hey what do you mean by if the clock is changed ??

Comment: @Kiran regardless, the `Date` constructor is doing the same thing. If you look up the source code, `public Date() {
         this(System.currentTimeMillis());
     }`

Comment: @Kiran I don't know of any system, or any reason you might have a multi-threaded issue obtaining the time.

Comment: @Kiran I mean that, if somebody manually changes the time on the device running this application backward, the current time could be less than the timestamp you're comparing against.  The code in the example wouldn't have a problem with that, but if you were going to store this information and maybe perform computations with it, it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to try in this way

```
    long timeStamp = 1375715967249l;
    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ((currTime - timeStamp) > 10*60*1000) {
        System.out.println("Greater than 10 minutes since executed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Lesser than 10 minutes since executed");
    }
```

10min = 10*60*1000 ms

Comment: Or TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10), which is conveys explicitly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX timestamps don't care about Timezones, UTC leap seconds or anything. It's just a number linearly measuring the passing of time. If you don't care about wallclock time either, there's no problem. You just have to take care that you convert your source material to UNIX timestamps in the right manner.